# Magento 2.3.3 View Order not working after PayU integration

Tags: magento2.3.3

**Summary:** Not able to open any orders post payu integration

**Environment details:**

Magento 2.3.3, Linux server (cloud)

Php 7.2

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Download the PayuIndia plugin for magenton 2.3.3 (this was given directly by the payu support team)

2. Install via composer/command line/web wizard etc. (end the result remained same.)

3. Admin Dashboard>Stores>Configuration>Sales>Payment Methods> enable payu gateway

4. Add products to cart, checkout using payu payment gateway

5. Go to Admin Dashboard>Sales>Order click on any order

**Expected result:** 
The order details/view page should appear.

**Actual result:**

 `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PayUIndia\Payu\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Verify' not found in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:116 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('PayUIndia\Payu...', Array) #1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('PayUIndia\Payu...', Array) #2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/BlockFactory.php(46): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('PayUIndia\Payu...', Array) #3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php(268): Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory->createBlock('PayUIndia\Payu...', Array) #4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php(248): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->getBlockInstance('PayUIndia\ in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 116`

Answer (score 0):

Try execute below commands in magento.

- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento setup:di:compile
- php bin/magento cache:clean
- php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: Thank you Hamendra Sunthwal. I had ran all the above comments, integration was successful and able to make payment using the PayU, however the issue was on Sales>Order view.